# Domain masking across different servers with Htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a Wordpress install on **domain1.com/blog** but ideally I would like it to display as **sub.domain2.com/blog**.

These domains are on separate servers. Ideally I would install WP on same server as domain2 but this isn't possible right now.

I've been able to get sub.domain2.com/blog to display the WP homepage but is it possible for htaccess and apache to rewrite the urls on domain1.com to display as sub.domain2.com?

Other than simple url rewrites I have limited experience with htaccess but I suspect for security reasons this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can of course, redirect your requests on `domain1.com` to `sub.domain2.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(blog/.*)$ http://sub.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Put the above in a htaccess file for the `domain1.com`.